# Check if two collections have common part

Tags: hive

I have a hive table in which two columns are arrays (created using collect_set built in function). I would like to get only those rows in which "any element in col1 = any element in col2", so simply they have any common part. I see that there is a array_contains(Array, value) function, but it needs one value, not a collection. Is it possible to express such condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` array elements and use simple `where` condition

See [explode UDTF manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t1.element from table
    LATERAL VIEW explode(col1) t1 as element
    LATERAL VIEW explode(col2) t2 as element 
    where t1.element = t2.element;
```